Trying to create dynamic tasks in airflow by reading metadata from snowflake
I'm trying to create dynamic tasks in airflow by reading metadata from snowflake. I have created a dag, but my dag is making calls to snowflake for every 30secs when ever the dag refreshes and this is ending up in burning snowflake credits. I tried with xcoms and @tasks but im getting below errors
TypeError: 'PythonOperator' object is not iterable
TypeError: 'XCom' object is not iterable
DAG 1: This is creating dynamic tasks by reading metadata from snowflake, but it is keep on calling snowflake and burning the credits.
Code: attached is the expected outcome picture
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from airflow.models import Variable
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pytz

import os
import sys
import time
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
path = "/".join(path.split('/')[:-2])
utils_path = path+'/'+'src/utils'
#print(utils_path)
sys.path.append(utils_path)
import util

odbc_conn_id = "DB2"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 22),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'email': [''],
    'retries': 1,
}
pipeline_name = 'dynamic task dag'
dag = DAG(pipeline_name,
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=None,
          catchup=False,
          max_active_tasks=140
           )

tab_list = []

def snflk_conn():
    snowflake_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id="Snowflake_Conn_Dev")
    conn = snowflake_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor

def snowflake_metadata():
    global tab_list
    cursor = snflk_conn()

    sql = '''query for metadata'''

    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in results:
        tab_list.append(row)

    cursor.close()


def generate_tasks(**context):
    global tab_list
    tasks = []
    for row in tab_list:
        attributes = row[:3]
        dymc_task_id = '.'.join(attributes)
        start_time = datetime.now()
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=dymc_task_id,
            python_callable=source_table,
            op_kwargs={'task_id': dymc_task_id, 'attributes': row, 'task_name' : dymc_task_id, 'start_time' : start_time, 'pipeline_name': pipeline_name },
            retries=2,
            dag=dag,
            queue="orca-a160",
            email_on_failure=True
        )
        tasks.append(task)
    return tasks


def source_table(task_id,attributes, task_name, start_time,pipeline_name, cursor=snflk_conn()):
    try:
        run_task_id = int(time.time())
        from io import BytesIO
        def sqlserver_connect(ti,**context):
            extract_sql = f"{select_with_new_cols} {where_clause}"
            print("Initializing connection to get data from Source: {}, Schema:{}, DB: {}, Table: {}, Facility_id: {} in CST timezone:{}".format(source, schema, db, table, fclty_id, load_date))
            sql = "{}".format(extract_sql)
            util.src_to_adls(odbc_conn_id,sql,source,table,db,fclty_id,Variable.get("tenantid"),Variable.get("clientid"),Variable.get("client_secret"))            
        
        dag_obj = sqlserver_connect('dag_obj')
        upd_tsk_s_tbl = util.upd_tsk_s_tbl(pipeline_name,run_task_id)
        cursor.execute_async(upd_tsk_s_tbl)
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(-1)


snowflake_metadata()  #this line of code is making the conn to snowflake, but if i remove this here it is not creating dynamic tasks


#operators

def start_task(cursor=snflk_conn(),**context):
    _start_task_upd = util.start_task_upd(pipeline_name)
    cursor.execute(_start_task_upd)

def end_task(cursor=snflk_conn(),**context):
    _upd_log_s_tbl = util.upd_log_s_tbl(pipeline_name)
    cursor.execute(_upd_log_s_tbl)
    util.send_email("success",pipeline_name)

start_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='start_task',
        python_callable=start_task)
    
# start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)

get_snowflake_metadata = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_sf_metadata',
    python_callable=snowflake_metadata,
    dag=dag)

dynamic_tasks = generate_tasks()

end_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='end_task',
        python_callable=end_task
    )
# end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task', dag=dag)

# Set up task dependencies
start_task >> get_snowflake_metadata

for dynamic_task in dynamic_tasks:
    get_snowflake_metadata >> dynamic_task >>end_task 
 
# Run the DAG
dag.run()type here

Dag2: in this DAG I'm not calling the snowflake_metadata directly, here im getting python operator not iterable error. tried different ways to over come this but it is not working
code:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from airflow.models import Variable
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pytz
from snowflake_wrapper import *
import os
import sys
import time
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
path = "/".join(path.split('/')[:-2])
utils_path = path+'/'+'src/utils'
#print(utils_path)
sys.path.append(utils_path)
import util

odbc_conn_id = "DB2"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 4, 22),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'email': [''],
    'retries': 1,
}
pipeline_name = 'test_dag5' 
dag = DAG(pipeline_name,
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=None,
          catchup=False,
          max_active_tasks=140
           )

tab_list = []

def snflk_conn():
    snowflake_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id="Snowflake_Conn_Dev")
    conn = snowflake_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor

def generate_tasks(metadata_func, **context):
    global tab_list
    tasks = []
    for row in tab_list:
        attributes = row[:3]
        dymc_task_id = '.'.join(attributes)
        start_time = datetime.now()
        task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=dymc_task_id,
            python_callable=source_table,
            op_kwargs={'task_id': dymc_task_id, 'attributes': row, 'task_name' : dymc_task_id, 'start_time' : start_time, 'pipeline_name': pipeline_name },
            retries=2,
            dag=dag,
            queue="orca-a160",
            email_on_failure=True
        )
        tasks.append(task)
    return tasks


def source_table(task_id,attributes, task_name, start_time,pipeline_name, cursor=snflk_conn()):
    try:
        run_task_id = int(time.time())

        start_tsk_insert = util.insrt_log_tbl(pipeline_name,task_name,start_time,run_task_id)
        cursor.execute_async(start_tsk_insert)
        from io import BytesIO
        def sqlserver_connect(ti,**context):
            source, schema, table, db, fclty_id, select_query, where_clause = attributes
            extract_sql = f"{select_with_new_cols} {where_clause}"
            print("Initializing connection to get data from Source: {}, Schema:{}, DB: {}, Table: {}, Facility_id: {} in CST timezone:{}".format(source, schema, db, table, fclty_id, load_date))
            sql = "{}".format(extract_sql)
            util.src_to_adls(odbc_conn_id,sql,source,table,db,fclty_id,Variable.get("tenantid"),Variable.get("clientid"),Variable.get("client_secret"))            
        
        dag_obj = sqlserver_connect('dag_obj')
        upd_tsk_s_tbl = util.upd_tsk_s_tbl(pipeline_name,run_task_id)
        cursor.execute_async(upd_tsk_s_tbl)

    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(-1)

#operators

def start_task(cursor=snflk_conn(),**context):
    _start_task_upd = util.start_task_upd(pipeline_name)
    cursor.execute(_start_task_upd)

def end_task(cursor=snflk_conn(),**context):
    _upd_log_s_tbl = util.upd_log_s_tbl(pipeline_name)
    cursor.execute(_upd_log_s_tbl)
    util.send_email("success",pipeline_name)

start_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='start_task',
        python_callable=start_task)
    

get_snowflake_metadata = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_sf_metadata',
    python_callable=snowflake_metadata,
    dag=dag)

#dynamic_tasks = generate_tasks()

# Set up task dependencies
dynamic_tasks = PythonOperator(
    task_id='dynamic_tasks',
    python_callable=generate_tasks,
    op_args=[snowflake_metadata],  # Pass snowflake_metadata as argument
    dag=dag
)

end_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='end_task',
        python_callable=end_task
    )
# end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task', dag=dag)
# Set up task dependencies
start_task >> get_snowflake_metadata >> dynamic_tasks >> end_task

# Loop through dynamic tasks and set dependencies
for dynamic_task in dynamic_tasks:
    dynamic_task >> end_task

